# How to show Bootstrap modal using CSS which also blocks out rest of screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Excuse me but I am new to Bootstrap.

I am wanting to show a modal using a CSS class rather than JavaScript (it is easier in this particular situation which uses ASP.NET UpdatePanels).

I can do this simply with:

```
<div id="popup" class="modal show">
```

But I want the rest of the screen to be blocked and greyed out, the same as when the JavaScript .modal("show") method is used.

I tried adding *data-backdrop="static"* but that didn't do anything.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible using a class alone.

It [can be done](http://jsfiddle.net/h3WDq/10/) if you wrap the modal in another element, using the `modal-backdrop` class.

```
<div class="modal-backdrop">
    <div id="myModal1" class="modal show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3>Standard Selectpickers</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <select class="selectpicker" data-container="body">
                <option>Mustard</option>
                <option>Ketchup</option>
                <option>Relish</option>
            </select>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I ended up adding "fade in" classes to make it transparent and did not wrap the popup as it made the popup transparent too. I ended up with <div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div><div id="popup" class="modal show"...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ui-bootstrap-tpls.js and what worked for me is that I searched in the whole project for **fade** and found 3 places where this was being set in the mentioned file.

I went through the find results and saw that 2 of the changes were being done on the modal and the other one was being set on the tool tip animation. Note the difference in below code

```
'uib-modal-animation-class': 'fade'
'tooltip-animation-class="fade"'
```

What I did to solve the issue was to add the **show** class for the uib-modal

```
'uib-modal-animation-class': 'fade show'
```